# Populating field with max M value of feature using Python in ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser

I need to calculate the max M value for a line feature using Python in ArcGIS 10 Field Calculator but I cannot figure it out.  In 9.3 I used the follow VBA expression…

```
**Pre-Logic VBA Script Code:**
dim m as imcollection
set m = [shape]
dim d as double 
d = m.mmax

**EndStation =:**
d
```

Comment: You are also able to use VBA in ArcGIS 10 also, if you want too. You just tick the box VBA, instead of Python when in the field calculator.

Comment: With the python parser selected
!Shape.extent.XMax!  produces the maximum X of a feature extent perhaps
!Shape.MMax! might work.  sorry I don't have an M-enabled file to check on, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: I have tried using my old VBA code but it won't work in 10.

Comment: If I put !Shape.MMax! in the codeblock what would I put EndStation equal to?

Comment: Since I can't try it, check the Python parser, don't toggle on the code block, simply select the field, launch the field calculator and paste in the code snippet.  It isn't a function (def) just a field calculator expression, like !shape.area! will calculate area for polygons.

Comment: I agree with what your thinking but that didn't work either.  thanks for your input.

Comment: response exist on [Geonet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/93191) with explainations

Answer (score 4):

use field calc to return the MAX M measures:

```
!Shape.extent.MMax!
```

use field calc to return the Min M measures:

```
!Shape.extent.MMin!
```

you can then calculate the M-length of the line using subtraction.

Answer (score 3):

Use `!shape.extent.mmax!` to return the max measures for routes.